# Can through-hole leads be cut level with the PCB back while maintaining good connectivity?

Tags: pcb-design, through-hole, manufacturing-process

If I'm using confusing terminology I apologize, this is relatively new to me and my first post on stack exchange.

My question is:  Can through-hole leads be cut and filed level with the PCB back while maintaining good connectivity?  I need a flush/flat surface on the rear PCB.

Further details:

I'm looking at using a through hole mounted CR2016 battery holder on a circuit but the leads need to be level with the back of the PCB due to size constraints. I've previously used SMD battery holders but the wings for the pads are too large for my new design, hence why I'm considering through mounted.

I've soldered both SMD and through hole and also ordered both designs from circuit board makers but I've never asked them to file down the leads to be level with the PCB back. I'm considering options such as seeedstudios or similar for the final item but I'm unsure if it is reasonable.

Comment: You *can*, but cutting leads flush after soldering stresses the joint significantly. Cutting them prior to soldering means you may not be able to get a good solder joint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IPC Class 1 and 2 require only that the "End is discernable in solder".

Cutting the leads before soldering would likely expose some non-plated material which might affect the joint (especially) if it's left for long before soldering. Cutting after soldering requires either re-soldering or 10x visual inspection.

Since the battery + holder has significant mass, the strength of the joints is important so you might want to do some testing (such as drop testing).

This is not standard handling, so it will be up to the PCBA house whether they want to do it and how much they want to charge. They may tell you they'll do everything but and you can do it yourself.